# How to display text on canvas without antialiasing

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, font-face, antialiasing

Is it possible to display text on canvas without antialiasing?

I am trying to display a fixed monospace font https://int10h.org/oldschool-pc-fonts/fontlist/font?ast_premiumexec

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: "AST";
                src: url(web_ast_premiumexec.woff) format('woff');
            }
            div {
                font-family: "AST";
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            canvas {
                font-smooth: never;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: none;
                /* image-rendering: pixelated; image-rendering: crisp-edges; */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>А</div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="32" height="32"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setpixelated(context){
                context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;       /* standard */
                context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;    /* Firefox */
                context.oImageSmoothingEnabled = false;      /* Opera */
                context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false; /* Safari */
                context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;     /* IE */
                context.imageSmoothingEnabled= false
            }

            var f = new FontFace('AST', 'url(web_ast_premiumexec.woff)');
            f.load().then(function() {
                const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                setpixelated(ctx)
                ctx.font = "16px AST"
                ctx.fillstyle='#00f';
                ctx.filter = 'none';
                ctx.fillText('А', 0, 16);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the output. 'A' at the top is from the "div" element. And 'A' at the bottom is from canvas.

[image: Output]

Comment: In addition to what the duplicate states there, note that it is quite clear from your screenshot that you are on a High-DPI monitor. CSS will scale your canvas, you need to scale its buffer size (through `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` by the actual pixel-ratio of the monitor (can be approximated by `window.devicePixelRatio`), and then let the CSS *shrink* it by setting its `style.width` and height to the expected sizes.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the duplication, apparently I was googling the wrong thing. In the end I didn't even need the antialiasing to be turned off, your comment helped me to solve my task. My main problem was caused by the High-DPI monitor, as you've noticed. It was enough to solve my issue:```canvas.width *= window.devicePixelRatio; canvas.height *= window.devicePixelRatio; canvas.style.width = 32; canvas.style.height = 32;```